# Is this SSHD config appropriate / secure

Tags: security, configuration, openssh, sshd

On the latest Debian Stretch I installed an OpenSSH server which I set up under the following conditions.

- no root login
- no password authentication / force public key authentication
- authentication by users of the group `sshusers` only
- 3 concurrent connections per user
- 1 authentication try per login attempt
- authentication timeout of 20 seconds

I'm using the latest OpenSSH `OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6, OpenSSL 1.0.2r  26 Feb 2019`

```
# $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Protocol 2
KerberosAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication no
AddressFamily inet
Port 22
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
LoginGraceTime 20s
MaxAuthTries 1
MaxStartups 3
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PermitRootLogin no
AllowGroups sshusers
```

I created the config above based on this article from 2005 which I tried to understand as much as possible. So I discovered `RSAAuthentication` is deprecated and removed it, I moved from DSA to RSA ...

My question is: Is this configuration secure or did I miss something important or did I misconfigured something?

I digged into the man page but I really don't understand everything clearly.

Comment: It really depends on the security level you are targetting ... but you could also add some filters on old `Ciphers`, `KeyAlgorithms` and `MACs`.

Comment: side note, but you could also implement external firewall here, that would filter out bots and break-in-tries (example: [fail2ban](https://www.booleanworld.com/protecting-ssh-fail2ban/))

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the support for weak ciphers such as Arcfour, blowfish, triple DES...